# JS - If statement with many conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My goal was to determine if an array contained any falsey elements and create a new array without those elements. I came up with a HORRIBLY ugly function but i just couldnt figure out a better way to write it.

```
    function bouncer(arr) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i] !== false ) {
      if (arr[i] !== NaN) {
        if (arr[i] !== "") {
          if (arr[i] !== 0) {
            if (arr[i] !== undefined) {
              if (arr[i] !== null) {
      newArray.push(arr[i]);
    }}}}}}
  return newArray;


}

bouncer([7, 'ate', '', false, 9]);
```

I tried using an if statement using miltiple conditions like

```
if (arr[i] !== false || arr[i] !== "")
```

But when I did that it wouldnt catch both conditions for some reason. what would have been a simpler way to do this ?

Comment: You need `if (arr[i] !== false && arr[i] !== "")` NOT ||

Comment: *Hint*: `||` means ***OR*** `&&` means ***AND***.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with this code? I often have many if statements too.

Comment: I don't think you understand the point of a value being "falsey" the idea is that a falsey value evaluates to `false`. the whole point is to avoid doing what you just did. See @Nina Scholz's answer

Answer (score 1):

You are using OR, should use AND instead:

```
if (arr[i] !== false && arr[i] !== "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `arr[i]` is truthy and then push the value.

```
arr[i] && newArray.push(arr[i]);
```

Complete code:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    var newArray = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] && newArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Or with `Array.filter`:

```
newArr = arr.filter(function (a) { return a; });
```

Answer (score 1):

A more readable version of @Nina Scholz's answer would be to explicitly check for truthiness without relying on short circuiting.

```
if (arr[i]) { newArray.push(arr[i]); }
```

Of course for your situation, you could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
newArr = arr.filter(function(el){ return el == true; });
```

Comment: comparing with true? really?

Comment: @NinaScholz I wanted to make it clear to him what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use filter.

```
var arr1 = [0, 1, false, '', 'zero', null];
var arr2 = arr1.filter(function (item) {
  return !!item;
});
console.log(arr2); // [1, 'zero']
```

Documentation for filter can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter